# Elastisearch : bool with regexp, filter and aggs

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, filter, aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am completely new to AWS ElastiSearch and am trying to do something on a dataset about tagged movies. The dataset has five columns : `genres, movieId, tag, title, userId`. The year of each movie is contained in the title like so `Waterworld (1995)`.
I want to see how many movies with the tag `true story` were produced in 2002.
Since I first have to match the date, then filter with the tag and finally count the movies I tried doing it with a bool like so:

```
GET tagged_movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "title": "(2002)"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tag": "true story"
          }
        }
      ],
      "aggs": {
        "by_numberofmovies": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "movieId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the following error :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "[18:7] [bool] unknown field [aggs]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "[18:7] [bool] unknown field [aggs]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

which I don't understand at all since the bool should recognize `aggs`. I've tried looking in the documentation as well as on the internet but it says that bool should indeed recognize the `aggs`. Could someone guide to where the problem might be ?

Here is an example of a the sample document that this query should match:

```
{
        "_index" : "tagged_movies",
        "_id" : "EgADsX8B2WnPqWZmot9b",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2011-03-22T04:22:48.000+01:00",
          "genres" : "Comedy",
          "movieId" : 5283,
          "tag" : "true story",
          "title" : "National Lampoon's Van Wilder (2002)",
          "userId" : 121,
          "timestamp" : "2011-03-22 04:22:48"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aggs` can't be inside the query block, `aggs` and `query` are siblings, you correct query should be like below

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "regexp": {
                        "title": "(2002)"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "tag": "true story"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_numberofmovies": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "movieId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I now get another error : `{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line" : 19,
        "col" : 5
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line" : 19,
    "col" : 5
  },
  "status" : 400
}`

Comment: @cped updated query, try now

Comment: I get the following output 
`{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_numberofmovies" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
` when the result should be 6

Comment: @cped, can you share your sample documents which you think should come in search result, maybe query which you formed needs some tunning.

Comment: edited my post to put in an example of sample documents and the result should be 4 sorry.

Comment: Here , `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpedroni/data/main/tagged_movies.csv` I imported the csv file to my github account

Comment: @cped please share your index mapping and setting as well.

Comment: Here are my settings : `{
  "tagged_movies" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "tagged_movies",
        "creation_date" : "1647942278537",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "L2s9mB-hQw2FJZHy8LyF9w",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "8010099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: And my mapping : `"properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "genres" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "movieId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "tag" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "userId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243385/discussion-between-amit-and-cped).